# Combining string elements from two separate arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays

```
names = ["name1", "name2"]
tracks = ["track1", "track2"]
```

I'm trying to combine the two arrays into one new array

```
data => ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

I tried the following

```
1)   @data = @name.zip(@tracks)flatten 
     produces ["name1", "track1", "name2", "track2"]

2)   @data = @name.at(0).concat(@tracks.at(0)) + @name.at(1).concat(@tracks.at(1))
     produces ["name1track1name2track2"]

3)   @name.each do |n|
      @tracks.each do |t|
       @data.push n + " " + t
       end
     end
     produces ["name1 track1", "name1 track2", "name2 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

I cannot seem to solve this problem. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Those new to SO commonly select an answer too soon (and thereby discourage other answers) or never select an answer.  If at least one answer meets your needs--as here (considering your comment on @steenslag's answer)--you should select the one you like best.  There's no rush, just don't forget to do it.  Have a look at this [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 6):

```
names  = ["name1", "name2"] #note the "="
tracks = ["track1", "track2"]

p names.zip(tracks).map{|e| e.join(" ")}
#=> ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

Comment: I went with this answer and it has worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
data = []
names.each_with_index {|x,y| data << "#{x} #{tracks[y]}" }
data # => ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names.map {|name| "#{name} #{tracks[names.index(name)]}"}
=> ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

Comment: If `names => ['cat', 'cat']` there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way to do it:

```
names = ["name1", "name2"]
tracks = ["track1", "track2"]

names.zip(tracks).map { |a| a.join(" ") }
# => ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

First,

```
names.zip(tracks)
```

gives us

```
[["name1", "track1"], ["name2", "track2"]]
```

And then we join the inner arrays with a space using `map`

Answer (score 0):

I like the [product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product) method

```
=> array_size = names.size
=> names.product(tracks).
     each_with_index.
     map { |x,i| x.join(" ") if (i % array_size - i / array_size).zero? }.compact
=> ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

Comment: If `array.size => 1,000`, you'd create an array with one million elements, then throw away 999,000 of them!

Comment: yeap, didn't say it was, fast or cheap. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
names.map { |s| s << ' ' << tracks.shift }
  #=> ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

If `names` (and/or `tracks`) cannot be modified, this would have to operate on a copy.

A variant:

```
[].tap { |a| names.size.times {a << (names.shift + ' ' + tracks.shift) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different way :

```
names  = ["name1", "name2"] 
tracks = ["track1", "track2"]

names.each_index.map { |i| "#{names[i]} #{tracks[i]}" }
# => ["name1 track1", "name2 track2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, very similar to @steenslag's (I sometimes hate opening blocks :-) )

```
names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
tracks = ["track1", "track2", "track3"]

names.zip([' '] * names.length, tracks).map(&:join)
=> ["name1 track1", "name2 track2", "name3 track3"]
```